# Running multiple test case on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to run my integration test on `Firebase Test Lab`.

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev.dart
./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest -Ptarget=lib/main_dev.dart
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/login_test.dart
```

This code generates `app-debug-androidTest.apk` and `app-debug.apk` and once I upload them in `Test Lab` Test are executed perfectly.

Now the issue is I have many test files under `integration_test`. I am not sure how to create a `app-debug-androidTest.apk`  that includes all the testcases under `integration_test`.

I did try the following:

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev.dart
./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest -Ptarget=lib/main_dev.dart
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=test_driver/integration_test.dart
```

but this stuck test at black screen which is I thing weird but a correct behavior as while running the integration test in local device also we need to provide target along with the driver.

So for Local I have a script

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/login_test.dart

flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/register_test.dart
```

which runs the all the Integration code.

So my question is how to upload all the test cases.

Or do we have to make build for each test case

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/login_test.dart
```

then upload it to the Test Lab then again

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/register_test.dart
```

and upload again?

Answer (score 3):

I have just encountered the same issue. For future reference for other people, what I did was to import all the tests into one single file `all_tests.dart`.

Let's say the directory structure is

```html
integration_test/
  test1.dart
  test2.dart
  test3.dart
  all_tests.dart
```

In `all_tests.dart`, I imported all the tests in:

```html
import 'test1.dart' as test1;
import 'test2.dart' as test2;

void main() {
  test1.main();
  test2.main();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is this working? I get to launch only the first file, then I get "All tests passed." and the other are skipped.

Comment: EDIT: It actually works, but not if you're using the screenshot approach explained here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#screenshots

Comment: It's not working for me, it is said "No tests found". Could you share a more detailed gist? 

Btw it's only working on flutter integration test (flutter drive)

Comment: With the new flutter integration test, you can run the whole folder I think. Just need to specify the directory, that's it. @TijaniRF

Comment: @AnhPham it is indeed working if I run it from Vscode, all of the integration tests are running. But it is not working if I used the instrumentation test as the OP specified

Comment: This approach didn't work for us. Even when running couple of test files together. While running the big suite with `flutter test integration_test/` we observed that between test run there is an additional build happening, while slow that step is creating reliability

Comment: Appending the above comment, I was able to get rid of flakiness by creating additional groups within tests. We had setup/teardown with getit DI setup and that was getting messed up without group.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem where there was no real way to get back to a clean app state after a test was run. Clearing the app data between the tests helped me a lot.

With

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

```
tearDown(() async {
  final filesDirPath = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
  if (Directory(filesDirPath).existsSync()) {
    await Directory(filesDirPath).delete(recursive: true);
  }
});
```

There could be more directories to remove like `getTemporaryDirectory()`, but this is usually where the user data is saved.